# Which one is correct here- attacks or attackers?

Tags: word-choice

A [blog](http://www.hindustantimes.com/tech/pak-based-cyber-attack-of-use-phishing-to-target-indian-defence-sites/story-6nFi8D2FzFiOi45jN84bFO.html)'s title is following:

> Pak-based cyber ***attacks*** use phishing to target Indian defence sites

IMO, if we remove 'use phishing' then 'attacks' is okay in this title because an attack cannot 'use' anything including phishing. In a way, 'attackers' looks more proper for this title.

Is my opinion right? I know the question is quite simple, but I am not sure about 'attacks' is written here in an idiomatic manner.

Comment: Why do you think an attack cannot use something?

Comment: "Cyber attacks use" is fairly common. For example, _"Your business depends on the web, email and file exchange. That's why over 90% of cyber attacks use those communication channels to infiltrate your organization ..."_ ([source](https://www.fireeye.com/solutions/enterprise-network-security.html)) You could say "cyber attackers" and have the same meaning. Sometimes a cyber attack is not actively being conducted by a person. Often attacks are automated, like a virus that sends phishing e-mails from an infected computer, so "attacks use" may be a little more precise.

Answer (score 3):

Good question.

In such special structure, the subject is a noun often inanimate. And, it's okay. Here, the subject is 'attacks' that use phishing to target Indian defense sites.

If you are confused, I'll get you another example where you'll think that 'citizens' should be the choice!

> The ***city witnesses*** huge traffic on Mondays

But, here, 'city' is the subject, and it *can* witness!

Comment: OP doesn't explicitly say so, but I guess you're right that his misgivings arise from the mistaken assumption that only sentient entities with goals can mount an *attack*. Given which, you may be better placed than most native speakers to recognize this and answer appropriately. Is there any tendency in your own native language to avoid using "purposeful" verbs with inanimate subjects? What about "feeling-based" verbs, as in [*The earth **suffered** perpetual drought*](http://www.lyricsfreak.com/l/loudon+wainwright+iii/the+man+who+couldnt+cry_21025471.html) ???

Comment: In my native/national language, all inanimate/animate nouns have *gender*... so there's no problem for that. @FumbleFingers